# How would I push an object to this nested file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My file has the following structure and I want to pass an object into the responses array, but it needs to go into the right comment responses array based on the post _id matching and then the comment_id matching.

```
{
post1: {
  post: 'anything',
  comments: [
      {comment: 'anything', comment_id: RANDOM ID, responses: []},
      {comment: 'something else', comment_id: ANOTHER RANDOM ID, responses: []},
    ],
  _id: RANDOM ID
  }
}
```

How would I add this object to the mongodb database, to add comments I used

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.post}, {$push: {comments: newComment}})
```

But I'm not sure how this works for adding responses because there's essentially 2 layers that need to be authenticated before it's pushed to the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
   Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.post, 'comments.comment_id': req.body.commentId}, {$push: { comments: newComment}})
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't this just push to the comments, rather than push to the responses

Answer (score 0):

Considering this data:

```
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "post1" : {
        "_id" : "post_1",
        "post" : "anything",
        "comments" : [ 
            {
                "comment" : "anything",
                "comment_id" : "comment_1",
                "responses" : []
            }, 
            {
                "comment" : "something else",
                "comment_id" : "comment_2",
                "responses" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The correct way to do it is like this:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: 'abc',
    'post1._id': 'post_1',
    'post1.comments.comment_id': 'comment_1',
  },
  { $push: { 'post1.comments.$.responses': 'bla' } }
)
```

Note the `$` in the path of the update query which is selected by `{ 'post1.comments.comment_id': 'comment_1' }` in your conditional query.